# What are your most useful custom ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Validation Attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

What are the custom ASP.NET MVC model validation attributes that you use. It seems that there are a ton of possibilities (zip code, email address, date in the past, etc.) but I haven't found any good sources where these are shared. I'll start the list with the following:

[ASP.NET MVC 3 Credit Card Validator](http://benjii.me/2010/11/credit-card-validator-attribute-for-asp-net-mvc-3/)

Answer (score 4):

If you use the [MVC Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) project on codeplex you will get a bunch of ready-to-use validators like

**Operator Validators**

```
[Is]
[EqualTo]
[NotEqualTo]
[GreaterThan]
[LessThan]
[GreaterThanOrEqualTo]
[LessThanOrEqualTo]
```

**Required Validators**

```
[RequiredIf]
[RequiredIfNot]
[RequiredIfTrue]
[RequiredIfFalse]
[RequiredIfEmpty]
[RequiredIfNotEmpty]
[RequiredIfRegExMatch]
[RequiredIfNotRegExMatch]
```

Comment: Is foolproof becoming redundant now that validators in MVC 3.0 support contingency?

Comment: Can not give you a good answer on this. I did not had time to read as much as I would on MVC 3, sorry